# Getting resolved file path in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to find a file that has a folder in its path that has a dynamic name that changes as I publish some app. (it has a version # appended to it).

`C:\somefolder\application_1.0.5.0\myxmlfile.xml`

```
$FilePath = "C:\somefolder\application*\myxmlfile.xml"
```

Which works great, but I'm changing xml and need to save it again. Upon saving it it's complaining about an illegal character in the path "*".

```
[xml] $xml = Get-Content..
$xml.Save($FilePath)
```

How can I get the path that powershell actually resolved in `$FilePath` so that I can pass it to the xml save function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
PS > $FilePath = 'C:\Window*\win.ini'

PS > Convert-Path $FilePath
C:\Windows\win.ini
```

Comment: Interesting.  The help for convert-path says that wildcards aren't allowed.

Comment: @MikeShepard That is if you use the `LiteralPath` argument. This is implicily using the `Path` argument.

Comment: @MikeShepard yeah but it says that here too http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858

Comment: So the documentation is wrong in more than one place?

Answer (score 3):

the [Resolve-Path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858.aspx) cmdlet will convert wildcards to a full path. Alternatively you could use something like:

```
$filepattern = "C:\somefolder\application*\myxmlfile.xml"
$filepath = gci $filepattern  | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: Alias for Get-ChildItem. It is the PS equivalent of DIR or LS